# Use of flat map with list of list

Tags: java-8, java-stream, flatten

If I have a `List<List<Foo>>` I can use flat map to flatten the list. 
But I have by `MyClass` which has a `List<Foo>` and the `Foo` class has list of bars `List<Bar>` then I have to do something like this :

```
myClass.getFoos().stream().map(Foo::getBars).forEach({
    bar -> // some code
});
```

Is it possible to use flat map in this scenario so I can get list of bars from `MyClass` in one shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
myClass.getFoos().stream()
    .map(Foo::getBars)
    .flatMap(List::stream) // flatten the lists
    .forEach(...);
```

Note the exlcusive use of method references, which I find neater and easier to read than lambdas.

Comment: Great, I didn't know I can do flat map after map.

Answer (score 3):

```
myClass.getFoos()
        .stream() 
        .flatMap(x -> x.getBars().stream())
        .forEach(...)
```